# Unable to send email even when telnet connection is working

Tags: email, uwp, smtp

I am trying to send an email through my organisation's email with the help of SMTP however, the email isnt sending. I have tried using TelNet to test the network connection and it is connected.

[image: connection working]

Here are my codes for the web services

```
public List<string> sendEmail(string fromAdress, string toAddress, string subject, string body)
    {
        List<string> message = new List<string>();
        string msg = "";
        try
        {
            System.Net.Mail.MailAddress from = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(fromAdress);
            System.Net.Mail.MailAddress to = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(toAddress);
            string[] values = toAddress.Split(',');
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.From = from;

            for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
            {
                mail.To.Add(values[i].Trim());
            }

            System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
            client.Port = 25;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Host = "172.20.192.204";
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mail.Subject = subject;
            mail.Body = body;
            client.Send(mail);
            message.Add("success");
        }
        catch (SmtpFailedRecipientException ex)
        {
            // ex.FailedRecipient and ex.GetBaseException() should give you enough info.
            msg = ex.GetBaseException().ToString();
            message.Add(ex.GetBaseException().ToString());
        }
        return message;
    }
```

Comment: Did you get any error info? If you failed at least you should be able to get some info about this.

Comment: No error info is shown....

Answer (score 0):

Try with telnet (this is wthout ssl and without authentication)

```
telnet <your mail server domain> 25

Server>> 220-hello ...
mail from: <hello@your-email.com>

Server>> 250 ok ...
rcpt to: <email@to.com>

Server>> 250 ok ...
DATA

Server>> 354 Go ahead
Some text message    
.

Server>> 250 Queued as dfgdfgdfg
quit
Server>> 221 Good bye.
```

Example wit authentication: http://namarginesie.blox.pl/2007/03/HOW-TO-telnet-do-serwera-SMTP.html